# All applications closed when computer goes to sleep

Tags: suspend, power-management

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 on a Dell XPS 9560, and I have been having a pretty odd and extremely annoying issue with my system recently.

Every time I close the lid of the computer or unplug it from my docking station, there is about a 30% chance that all of the applications will be closed next time I open the lid.  The system does not log me out, only locks the workstation.

Is there any way to diagnose and/or repair this issue?